# Delete with params in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I use ADO.NET to delete some data from DB like this:

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Table where ID in (@idList);", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@idList", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                cmd.Parameters["@idList"].Value = stratIds;

                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //_logger.LogMessage(eLogLevel.ERROR, DateTime.Now, e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

That code executes without Exception but data wasn't deleted from DB.
When I use the same algorithm to insert or update DB everything is OK.
Does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 9):

You can't do that in regular TSQL, as the server treats `@idList` as a **single** value that happens to contain commas. However, if you use a `List<int>`, you can use dapper-dot-net, with

```
connection.Execute("delete from Table where ID in @ids", new { ids=listOfIds });
```

dapper figures out what you mean, and generates an appropriate parameterisation.

Another option is to send in a string and write a UDF to perform a "split" operation, then use that UDF in your query:

```
delete from Table where ID in (select Item from dbo.Split(@ids))
```

Comment: You said - "You can't do that in regular TSQL, as the server treats @idList as a single value that happens to contain commas" - In facts I can use code `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Table where ID in ("+stratIds+");", conn)` and everything works right. So I think I can replace string stratIds with param.

Comment: @Kate - I don't understand the comment

Comment: @Kate, SQL parameters don't work like that, your example using string concatenation will work, but parameters are not substituted out and treated like a string concatenation.

Comment: @Kate - your strategy for string concatenation is a SQL-Injection-attack waiting to happen.

Comment: That is why I want to use SqlParametr

Comment: @Kate and by using a parameter, you remove the ability to use IN, unless you hack around it

Answer (score 3):

According to Marc's Split-UDF, this is one working implementation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

And this is how you could call it:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE (ID IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@idList, ',')));
```

Comment: winning strategy in sql for a long time now.+1

Comment: be sure to mention the seminal: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html a classic

Answer (score 1):

I want to give this discussion a little more context. This seems to fall under the topic of "*how do I get multiple rows of data to sql*". In @Kate's case she is trying to DELETE-WHERE-IN, but useful strategies for this user case are very similar to strategies for UPDATE-FROM-WHERE-IN or INSERT INTO-SELECT FROM.  The way I see it  there are a few basic strategies.

### String Concatenation

This is the oldest and most basic way.  You do a simple  "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (" + someCSVString + ");"

- Super simple
- Easiest way to open yourself to a SQL Injection attack.
- Effort you put into cleansing the string would be better spent on one of the other solutions

### Object Mapper

As @MarcGravell suggested you can use something like dapper-dot-net, just as Linq-to-sql or Entity Framework would work.  Dapper lets you do `connection.Execute("delete from MyTable where ID in @ids", new { ids=listOfIds });`   Similarly Linq would let you do something like `from t in MyTable  where myIntArray.Contains( t.ID )`

- Object mappers are great.
- However, if your project is straight ADO this is a pretty serious change to accomplish a simple task.

### CSV Split

In this strategy you pass a CSV string to SQL, whether ad-hoc or as a stored procedure parameter.   The string is processed by a table valued UDF that returns the values as a single column table.

- This has been a winning strategy since SQL-2000
- @TimSchmelter gave a great example of a csv split function.
- If you google this there are hundreds of articles examining every aspect from the basics to performance analysis across various string lengths.

### Table Valued Parameters

In SQL 2008 custom "table types" can be defined.  Once the table type is defined it can be constructed in ADO and passed down as a parameter.

- The benefit here is it works for more scenarios than just an integer list -- it can support multiple columns
- strongly typed
- pull string processing back up to a layer/language that is quite good at it.
- This is a fairly large topic, but Table-Valued Parameters in [SQL Server 2008 (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) is a good starting point.